# how can i get custom content type's field's data?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want to create a custom **content-type** and many custom fields. Then I want
to get all field's value whiten different variables. 
how can I get all custom fields data ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Did you even bother doing a google search? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144947/how-do-i-access-a-field-value-for-an-entity-e-g-node-object

Comment: https://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-accessing-node-values-and-properties-loading